# Binding 2 Dependency Properties Together Without Name

Tags: c#, uwp

Is it possible to create a binding between two dependency properties, from code, without knowing the names of the dependency properties? In other words, I have 2 DependencyProperty instances and 2 DependencyObject instances, and I would like to create a Binding between them.

```
Binding newBinding = new Binding();
newBinding.Source = SourceDependencyObject;
newBinding.Path = ???;  // Get name from SourceDependencyProperty?

BindingOperations.SetBinding(TargetDependencyObject, TargetDependencyProperty, newBinding);
```

Comment: Any updates? Did my answer solve you problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SourceDependencyObject is a `DependencyObject`, it seems we should be able to get the name from the SourceDependencyProperty and set to the `Binding.Path`.

For example:

```
TextBlock SourceDependencyObject = new TextBlock();
SourceDependencyObject.Text = "Hello";
TextBlock TargetDependencyObject = new TextBlock();
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Source = SourceDependencyObject;
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Text");
BindingOperations.SetBinding(TargetDependencyObject, TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
Debug.WriteLine(TargetDependencyObject.Text);
```

If we do not set the Path, the TargetDependencyProperty will point to the SourceDependencyObject.

So if the SourceDependencyObject is `string`, `int` or other type. We do not need to set the [Binding.Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.path.aspx).

For example:

```
TextBlock SourceDependencyObject = new TextBlock();
SourceDependencyObject.Text = "Hello";
TextBlock TargetDependencyObject = new TextBlock();
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Source = SourceDependencyObject.Text;
//myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Text");
BindingOperations.SetBinding(TargetDependencyObject, TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
Debug.WriteLine(TargetDependencyObject.Text);
```